# Measuring time and doing actions in a game in C

Tags: c, game-physics

I'm trying to develop a game in C using conio for creating an ascii interface.

I have to control my hero in a maze and finding the exit, avoiding the enemies.

Each enemy should perform a move every 1 second.

But I don't know how to implement the control of my hero and the control of the movement of each enemy (every 1 second).

Is it possible to do this without using threads?

Comment: conio is an old interface for msdos. Try reading about ncurses instead. And check coroutines instead of thrads.

Comment: @ulix The use of `conio.h` indicates that @Zaratruta is most likely on windows so [PDCurses](https://pdcurses.sourceforge.io) would have been a better recommendation.

Comment: for timing, a thread sleep is pretty trivial. is there some reason you don't want to use it? if you want to improve the time accuracy you could profile the time it takes for your game to process the work each frame, and then sleep for the remaining time. you should probably do this because console I/O is slow. there will still be a random (in the order of ~1 ms) thread wakeup time but this shouldn't be a problem since you want a 1 second rate.

Comment: Let's suppose that conio is a requisite and that we need to do this without threads. Is it possible?

Comment: Yeah you just run a loop and eat CPU cycles to create the delay while also taking into account the time taken by actual work. This is very accurate because you don't have to worry about thread wakeup time. Swordfish's answer looks like its on track for that.

Comment: Also if the player is meant to have realtime control (moving smoothly in between your 1 sec ticks) you can actually check for player input every iteration of the loop.

Comment: conio.h is just fine for learning and toy programs. It's delightfully simple, relic from time when programmer actually had control of the PC.

Comment: @ChrisRollins But if I check for player input every iteration of the loop and the player doesn't press any key, this would freeze the actions of the enemies as well, right?

Comment: if you use something that blocks while waiting for input you would have that problem. there is a function in windows API to query keys and mouse clicks without blocking. make sure you check if the program is in front though. it still works while minimized or another program is active lol. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate

Answer (score 2):

```
time_t last_time_moved = 0;
time_t delay = 1;
int user_input;

for(;;) { // in your game loop
    time_t now = time(NULL); // check for the current time

    // ...

    if(_kbhit()) {
        user_input = _getch();

        // act on user input
    }

    // ...

    if(now > (last_time_moved + delay)) {

        // move your enemies

        last_time_moved = time(NULL);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: To add to this, kbhit() would be the function to call to detect user pressing keys in this loop. Also, adding a short sleep, like 10 ms, to the loop would reduce CPU usage without impacting responsiveness too much.

Comment: @4386427 Thank you, good point. without a delay of `1` it could trigger before one sec is over for sure.

Comment: But if the user doesn't press any key, the enemies will freeze, right?

Comment: @4386427 if time is called at xx:yy:35.87 and the next check occures at xx:yy:36.01 the delay is < 1s

Comment: @Zaratruta You should use `_kbhit()` to check if there is input to read and then `_getch()` to get it like @hyde suggested.